# ROS Groovy install error "Debian & Sources"

Tags: ros-groovy, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am the newbie of ROS, and i want to install it in Debian (acctually Mint Debian) by using source and compile it. I just follow the wiki "Installation/Source", and when I doing:

> ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install

there comes errors when compile PCL. The link errors shows missing some library like:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsensor_msgs 
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lroscpp_serialization 
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrosconsole 
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrostime

but actually these libs are compiled by catkin_make_isolated before, and there's no error compile them. I cd into "devel_isolated" directory, found rostime, rosconsole, roscpp_serialization, sensor_msgs are existed and there is a "lib" subdirectory in them.

How can I deal with these errors?

BTW, sorry for my poor English :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52975/ros-groovy-install-error-%22debian-&-sources%22/) by [reyoung](https://answers.ros.org/users/4022/reyoung/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-01-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is already a fix for that [here](https://github.com/ros-gbp/pcl-release/commit/bf43ffc0eebca4042c6765319c4dd211409d7ace)

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [reyoung](https://answers.ros.org/users/4022/reyoung/) on 2013-01-24**:
It works!!